# Is the positive part of the Zariski decomposition of a big $\mathbb{R}$-divisor big?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, divisors

I can't understand why the positive part of the Zariski decomposition of a big class is itself big.  More concretely:
let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $N^1_{\mathbb{R}}(X)$ be the Néron-Severi space associated to $X$. Let $D$ be a big class in $N^1_{\mathbb{R}}(X)$ and let $D=P_D+N_D$ be its Zariski decomposition. Recall that $P_D$ is an effective, nef $\mathbb{R}$-divisor and $N_D=\sum_i a_i C_i$ is an effective, negative $\mathbb{R}$-divisor, where "negative" means that the Gram-matrix $(C_i \cdot C_j)_{i,j}$ is negative definite. Moreover it holds $P_D \cdot C_i=0$ for every $i$.
How to show that $P_D$ is a big $\mathbb{R}$-divisor? It should be an elementary fact, but I can't see it...

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Write $D=\sum n_iD_i$, with $n_i>0$ and $D_i$ a big integral divisor. If $D_i=P_i+N_i$ is the Zariski decomposition of $D_i$, the $P_i$ are big, so 
 $P_D=\sum n_iP_i$ is big.

Comment: Why is $P_D$ ($N_D$) the sum of the positive parts (negative parts)?

Comment: Oh, right, this is not clear at all.

Comment: @Frant isn't it true that $P_D \geq \sum n_iP_i$ (equivalently, $N_D \leq \sum n_iN_i$)? That should be enough as big + effective = big.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Sincerely I don't know... So you are saying that to contruct the "new" positive part, we should just take off from $\sum_i n_i N_i$  some "components"?

Comment: One way to characterise $P$ is that it is the unique largest nef divisor with $D \geq P$, from which my claim is immediate. It is clearly maximal (adding a little bit of $N$ pushes it outside the nef cone), and uniqueness follows since $\max(P,P')$ is nef and $\leq D$ when $P, P'$ are (note that the Zariski decomposition is most naturally defined on the level of divisors, *before* passing to numerical equivalence). See Lemma 4.4 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4500) for the integral case.

Comment: You are right... I looked at the construction of the Zariski decomposition (also for $\mathbb{R}$-divisors). An argument can be the following: let $D=\sum_ia_iD_i$, where $D_i$ is integral and big and write $D_i=P_{D_i}+N_{D_i}$, we know from Lazarsfeld that $P_{D_i}$ is a big $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor. Now write $D=\sum_i (a_iP_{D_i}+a_iN_{D_i})$. By construction $P_D$ is the maximal nef "subdivisor" of $D$, with $D \geq P_D$. It follows that $P_D \geq \sum_i a_i P_{D_i}$, because this sum is effective and nef. But now $P_D=\sum_i a_iP_{D_i}+E$, where $E$ is an effective $\mathbb{R}$-divisor...

Comment: ... and so big+effective=big. I think the argument works. Thank you very much for your help. As I imagined it was an easy fact!

Answer (score 1):

My copy of Lazarsfeld is quarantined in my office, and I lack the reputation for a comment, so forgive me for a non-answer.  But I think there is a statement there to the effect that $h^0(\lfloor mD \rfloor) = h^0(\lfloor mP(D) \rfloor)$ for all $m$ (this is essentially from the definition, if you construct Zariski decomposition using the approach of Nakayama and specialize to dimension 2).  This would mean you are done except for the nuisance of rounding, but I think it should be true that an $\mathbb R$-divisor is big if and only if $h^0(\lfloor mD \rfloor)$ grows like $m^{\dim X}$.

Comment: Just to fill in the last step: this characterization is Proposition A.14 in Fujino's "[Fundamental theorems for semi log canonical pairs](https://doi.org/10.14231/AG-2014-011)."

Comment: Yes, @Tim Piyim, the statement is the following: Let $D=P+N$ be a big integral divisor, then the natural map $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(mD-\roundup{mN})) \to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(mD))$ is bijective for every $m \geq 1$. Sorry for the "\roundup" but I don't know how to do the symbol!